# Working on aws CodePipelines, Stack Creation failed every time

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloud9

I am trying to deploy a code pipeline stack from cloud9 terminal. Initially, deploy was successful and there were errors in Pipeline Build stage. I tried to fix these in code but deploying again never worked and I am getting this error continuously.

❌  PipelinesUsama failed: Error: The stack named PipelinesUsama failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

Before deploying, I deleted every s3 resource and all previous stacks of mine. The weird thing is if I try with a completely different name of Stack, error is still the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij4B1.png)

**Updating Issue**
I tried all the deletions. But error is still same. Now I am going to attach my pipeline_stack code and app code

**pipeline_stack.py**

```
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import pipelines
from aws_cdk import aws_codepipeline_actions as pipeline_actions
# from infra.infra_stage import InfraStage

class UsamaPipeline(cdk.Stack):
   def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        
        #Connecting to the code source
        source = pipelines.CodePipelineSource.git_hub(repo_string = "usama2021skipq/andromedaRepo_2021",
                                                    branch = "main", 
                                                    authentication = cdk.SecretValue.secrets_manager("usama_secret", 
                                                                                        json_field = "github_access"),
                                                    trigger = pipeline_actions.GitHubTrigger.POLL)
                                                    
        synth = pipelines.ShellStep('synth', input = source, 
                                    commands = ["cd UsamaAndromedaSkipQ/infra", "pip install -r requirements.txt",
                                                "npm install -g aws-cdk", "cdk synth"], 
                                    primary_output_directory = "UsamaAndromedaSkipQ/infra/cdk.out")
                                    
        pipeline = pipelines.CodePipeline(self, "UsamaPipeline", pipeline_name = "UsamaPipeline", synth = synth)
        
        # beta = InfraStage(self, "Beta", 
        #                 env = {"account" : "315997497220", "region" : "ap-southeast-1"})
        
        
        # prod = InfraStage(self, "Prod", 
        #                 env = {"account" : "315997497220", "region" : "ap-southeast-1"})
                        
        # pipeline.add_stage(beta)
        
        # pipeline.add_stage(prod)
```

**app.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import core
# from infra.infra_stack import InfraStackUsama
from infra.pipeline_stack import UsamaPipeline

# For consistency with TypeScript code, `cdk` is the preferred import name for
# the CDK's core module.  The following line also imports it as `core` for use
# with examples from the CDK Developer's Guide, which are in the process of
# being updated to use `cdk`.  You may delete this import if you don't need it.



app = core.App()
# InfraStackUsama(app, "InfraStackUsama",
    # If you don't specify 'env', this stack will be environment-agnostic.
    # Account/Region-dependent features and context lookups will not work,
    # but a single synthesized template can be deployed anywhere.

    # Uncomment the next line to specialize this stack for the AWS Account
    # and Region that are implied by the current CLI configuration.

    #env=core.Environment(account=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT'), region=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION')),

    # Uncomment the next line if you know exactly what Account and Region you
    # want to deploy the stack to. */

    #env=core.Environment(account='123456789012', region='us-east-1'),

    # For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html
    # )

UsamaPipeline(app, "UsamaPipeline", 
                    env = cdk.Environment(account = "315997497220", region = "us-east-2"))

app.synth()
```

Have a look, if you find something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the Cloud Formation stack, before trying again. Go to Cloud Formation service in AWS console. You will be able to see your stacks. Examine the Events, as they will help you understand, why the creation failed.

You can't create two stacks with the same name. You should be able however to:

- Update an existing stack
- Create a new stack with a difference name

If this isn't working for you, you need to check your code-pipeline directives.

For now, the easiest will be to use AWS Console to delete the stack and try again.